# problemas con cors de axios

Tags: ajax, vue.js, axios

Quiero hacer esta petición con axios. Me ayudan a traducirla.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
  if(this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", "https://api.apoyamostueconomia.com/api/auth/registro");

xhr.send();
```

Estoy utilizando losiguiente:

```js
 import axios form 'axios';
    
axios.create({
   baseURL: 'https://api.apoyamostueconomia.com/api/',
   withCredentials: true
});

axios.post('auth/register').then(res=>console.log(res), err=>console.log(err.response));
```

Pero solo funciona en firefox. No se porque motivo no funciona en google chrome.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Qué errores te genera en Google Chrome?

Comment: que no encuentra la cabecera Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Me di cuenta que laravel si necesita dos headers en el index para que funcione en todas las rutas.

Answer (score 0):

puedes probar si esto funciona.

```
Axios({
  method: 'POST',      
  withCredentials: true,
  url: 'https://api.apoyamostueconomia.com/api/auth/register'
}).then(response => {
  console.log(response.data)
}).catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: Por favor considera leer [answer], los aportes que son solo código se consideran de baja calidad, editar y explicar tu código no solo ayuda a quien preguntó sino también a toda la comunidad